# How to issue 410 header (gone) only for certain file types / extensions

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, header, http-headers

Short story: hacker adds a million pages with some strange extension (e.g. .drf)

Now, I want to issue 410 header via htaccess to these. This is what I have so far, but no work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.dfr$ 

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

RewriteRule ^.*\.dfr$ - [R=410]

# Not sure if I really need this, but whatever
ErrorDocument 404 default
```

With this, I still get wordpress 404 page, so obviously something missing/wrong

---

Update:

I tried this. Same result (wordpress 404). There are also some caching rules, from a popular plugin, but not putting those in there

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

ErrorDocument 404 default


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule \.dfr$ - [NC,G,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this rule just below `RewriteBase` line:

```
RewriteRule \.dfr$ - [NC,G,L]
```

You can also use flags `[NC,F]` to return more appropriate `403` (forbidden).

Comment: Did not fix. Still get wordpress page, and its 404 status

Comment: Did you place this rule just below top `RewriteBase /` line? If yes then may be it is due to some Wordpress cache/proxy plugin that is overriding ,htaccess